# QSqlQuery not display QString position

Tags: sql, qt

I catch such an error

```
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
```

Here is the code itself:

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString inputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "inputText :" << inputText;
    double zapros = inputText.toDouble();

    // считываем данные из базы
    QSqlQuery query;

    if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM " TABLE ";")){
        qDebug() << "Unable to execute query - exiting";
    }

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();

    double BarCode;
    QString Name;
    QDate Date;

    bool tex_per=false;
    while(query.next()){
        BarCode = query.value(rec.indexOf("BarCode")).toDouble();
        qDebug() << "BarCode :" <<BarCode;
        if(BarCode == zapros){
            Name = query.value(rec.indexOf("Message")).toString();
            Date = query.value(rec.indexOf("Date")).toDate();
            qDebug()<<"|"<<BarCode<<"|"<<Name<<"|"<<Date<<"|";
            tex_per = true;
        }
    }
    if(tex_per==false){
        qDebug()<<"Такой штрих-код в базе данных не имеется";
    }
}
```

output :

```
inputText : "1231321"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
BarCode : 4.00476e+12
Такой штрих-код в базе данных не имеется

inputText : "4690432003609"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
| 4.69043e+12 | "" | QDate("2017-08-12") |
BarCode : 4.00476e+12

inputText : "4004764390564"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
BarCode : 4.00476e+12
QSqlQuery::value: not positioned on a valid record
| 4.00476e+12 | "" | QDate("2018-03-25") |
```

(program) gets liquid data, but at the same time for some reason doesn’t give out a position called "name" which lies in the QString format. This is precisely the problem and the program gives `QSqlQuery :: value: not positioned on a valid record`

In the database, this `VARCHAR (255)` is inserted into the database using this line

```
query.bindValue(":Message",         data[1].toString());
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We need to check if there is such a "Message" field in the database

added code

```
    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
     //- news
    for(int i=0;i<rec.count();i++) { qDebug()<<"rec.fieldName("<<i<<"):"<<rec.fieldName(i); }
    //-
    double BarCode;
    QString Name;
    QDate Date;
```

output :

```
inputText : "4690432003609"
rec.fieldName( 0 ): "id"
rec.fieldName( 1 ): "BarCode"
rec.fieldName( 2 ): "Name"
rec.fieldName( 3 ): "Date"
```

there is no "Message" position, but there is a "Name"

all added code

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    QString inputText = ui->lineEdit->text();
    qDebug() << "inputText :" << inputText;
    double zapros = inputText.toDouble();

    // считываем данные из базы
    QSqlQuery query;

    if(!query.exec("SELECT * FROM " TABLE ";")){
        qDebug() << "Unable to execute query - exiting";
    }

    QSqlRecord rec = query.record();
    for(int i=0;i<rec.count();i++) { qDebug()<<"rec.fieldName("<<i<<"):"<<rec.fieldName(i); }

    double BarCode;
    QString Name;
    QDate Date;

    bool tex_per=false;
    while(query.next()){
        BarCode = query.value(rec.indexOf("BarCode")).toDouble();
        qDebug() << "BarCode :" <<BarCode;
        if(BarCode == zapros){
             Name = query.value(rec.indexOf("Name")).toString(); // to String()
            Date = query.value(rec.indexOf("Date")).toDate();
            qDebug()<<"|"<<BarCode<<"|"<<Name<<"|"<<Date<<"|";
            tex_per = true;
        }
    }
    if(tex_per==false){
        qDebug()<<"Такой штрих-код в базе данных не имеется";
    }
 }
```

all output :

```
inputText : "4690432003609"
rec.fieldName( 0 ): "id"
rec.fieldName( 1 ): "BarCode"
rec.fieldName( 2 ): "Name"
rec.fieldName( 3 ): "Date"
BarCode : 9.0238e+12
BarCode : 4.69043e+12
| 4.69043e+12 | "Корректирующая жидкость" | QDate("2017-08-12") |
```